# How to unset or change headers using Apache webserver?

Tags: apache, header, http-headers, content-security-policy, mod-headers

What I tried to do is to embed an iframe into a website and was faced with Content Security Policy.
I know this question was asked before, but I couldn’t find any working solution.

Error message:
*Content security policy: 'x-frame-options' will affect because of 'frame-ancestors' directive.*

What I tried so far, using the Apache module “mod_headers”:

- Header unset X-Frame-Options Header unset Content-Security-Policy
- Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"
- Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
- Header always setX-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://mydomain”

Any idea to get iframes embed, though Content security policy?

Comment: Remove all Header and test using `Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"`

Comment: thanks, I did a test with this, removed all other header and still get: Content security policy: 'x-frame-options' will affect because of 'frame-ancestors' directive.

Comment: where did you observe this error?

Comment: I got one message in firefox: Firefox prevented this page from loading in this way because the page has a content security policy that disallows it.
And one in firebug: Content Security Policy: Ignoring ‘x-frame-options’ because of ‘frame-ancestors’ directive.